# Conditional Formatting: Change color of Entire Row if any column value changes (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]Good evening,

I'm attempting to find the best solution for Changing an Entire row's font color (red) if any cell value changes (updated or inserted). *Edited comment: I'm also open utilizing a custom formula in with Apps Script*.

I have also included an Attachment for clarification. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Initially, I created a Custom Formula (below) that changes all font color to red when the Quantity column (G) is Greater than zero. But it needs to be modified to handle any cell value changes within an entire row.

```
Apply to any range: A5:M13,A16:M23,A26:M28,A31:M38 
Custom Formula is: = $G5:$G > 0
```

Comment: `Custom Formula is: = $G4:$G > 0` Are you sure that you don't mean `$G5:$G`; row 4 doesn't contain any transaction data.

Comment: Based on my understanding on what you are looking for it is very tricky to implement in pure Google Sheet formula and conditional formatting and very easy to implement on apps script and utilize the built in function onEdit. I understand that you are clear about not using Apps Script but would you open be open for it as alternate solution?

Comment: To clarify, yes I actually meant $G5:G

Comment: And @Barbanana, if Apps Script is a better approach, I'm open to creating a function in Apps Script that handles this requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Detect Changes and Change Font Color of Affected Row. (Alternate Solution)

It is very tricky to detect changes using only formulas. Alternate solution is using Apps Script. I have created a simple script for you to implement this gracefully.

### Code :

```
function onEdit(e) {
var changedRange = e.range;
var changedRow = changedRange.getRow();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var transformRange = sheet.getRange(changedRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
transformRange.setFontColor("Red");
}
```

### How it works on your Sheet:

[image]

### Reference:

[onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

[setFontColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

> **Please let me know if you need clarification with the Apps Script and how to implement this on your project**

Comment: Thanks for your additional guidance! Initially it worked as needed, then it stopped working. I'm not sure if I inadvertently hit Run in Apps Script.

Comment: How do I get the function to run automatically OnEdit again

Comment: I'm attempting to have this for Multiple tabs and I'm not sure if that is causing an issue. Here are the 3 functions for each tab:

Comment: function onEdit(e) {
var changedRange = e.range;
var changedRow = changedRange.getRow();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Planning"); // Please change the sheet to your sheet name.
var transformRange = sheet.getRange(changedRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
transformRange.setFontColor("Red");
}

Comment: function onEdit(e) {
var changedRange = e.range;
var changedRow = changedRange.getRow();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Foundation"); // Please change the sheet to your sheet name.
var transformRange = sheet.getRange(changedRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
transformRange.setFontColor("Red");
}

Comment: function onEdit(e) {
var changedRange = e.range;
var changedRow = changedRange.getRow();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Framing"); // Please change the sheet to your sheet name.
var transformRange = sheet.getRange(changedRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
transformRange.setFontColor("Red");
}

Comment: I understand, so you don't want to do this with 3 onEdit function we have to edit the script to cater 3 of the sheets. Let me make a quick modification

Comment: I have modified the script to get the active sheet where changes have been made, this is a quick fix. Please check the changes on the code part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

- `In apply to range`: include each of the ranges that you want to make conditional
- `Format Rules`

  - Custom Formula
  - `=$G:$G>0`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: conditional]

[image: sheet]